# How to play a local audio file in Tauri?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, audio, mp3, tauri

I'm working on a mp3 (audio) player on **Tauri** and **Vue.js**.

I tried multiple solution but none of them worked.

My player is using a simple video tag :

```c
<video ref="video" :key="queryUrl" controls>
    <source
      :key="queryUrl"
      :src="sourceUrl"
      ref="source"
      type="audio/mpeg"
    >
</video>
```

First I tried changing the source :

```c
const appDataDirPath = await appDataDir();
const filePath = await join(appDataDirPath, 'test.mp3');
sourceUrl.value = filePath;
```

But got this error :

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/hangel/AppData/Roaming/com.tauri.dev/test.mp3

Using Audio from javascript results to the same error :

```c
const audio = new Audio('C:\\Users\\hangel\\AppData\\Roaming\\com.tauri.dev\\test.mp3');
// Not allowed to load local resource
```

Then, I tried using the **convertFileSrc** from tauri documentation :

```c
const appDataDirPath = await appDataDir();
const filePath = await join(appDataDirPath, 'test.mp3');
const assetUrl = convertFileSrc(filePath);

source.value.src = assetUrl;
video.value.appendChild(source.value);
video.value.load();
```

But I also got an error :

> GET https://asset.localhost/C%3A%5CUsers%5Changel%5CAppData%5CRoaming%5Ccom.tauri.dev%5Ctest.mp3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My last attempt was using **readBinaryFile** from Tauri :

But I don't know what to do using the content of my file (**Uint8Array**).

```c
const content = await readBinaryFile('test.mp3', { dir: BaseDirectory.AppData });
// returns a Uint8Array
// what to do with this array ?
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tauri but generally unless the file is included as a source file of the app,  you aren't allowed to programmatically load/access files on users machines without their permission.  If you add a file uploader component and let the user choose a file to play, it might work better.

Answer (score 2):

You can load local audio (media) files using the **convertFileSrc** method from Tauri.

The documentation: https://tauri.app/fr/v1/api/js/tauri/#convertfilesrc

You need to follow these steps in order to use this method:

In the **tauri.conf.json**, you need to add protocol in **tauri.allowlist**:

```
  "protocol": {
    "all": true,
    "asset": true,
    "assetScope": ["**"]
  }
```

And this, still in **tauri.conf.json**, **tauri.allowlist**:

```
    "security": {
      "csp": "default-src 'self'; media-src 'self' asset: https://asset.localhost;"
    }
```

Then, you can load the mp3 file:

```
  import { appDataDir, join } from '@tauri-apps/api/path';
  import { convertFileSrc } from '@tauri-apps/api/tauri';

  const appDataDirPath = await appDataDir();
  const filePath = await join(appDataDirPath, 'test.mp3');
  const musicUrl = convertFileSrc(filePath);

  source.value.src = musicUrl;
  video.value.appendChild(source.value);
  video.value.load();
```